# <lightning:buttonIcon /> icons disappeared in community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

We recently migrated a bunch of our manually created SLDS code to the new lightning component variants and all was good until we checked back in this morning. All of a sudden none of the svg icons are showing in our community when using `<lightning:buttonIcon />'. We are using the standard utility icons like`utility:close` for our modal close buttons.

Is anyone aware of a known issue with these that was introduced recently or of a workaround? We could always revert back to our old setup but I am hoping to keep our code moving forward.

Here is an example of a modal close button using this new component:

```
<lightning:buttonIcon class="slds-modal__close" iconName="utility:close" alternativeText="Close" size="large" variant="bare-inverse" onclick="{!c.closeModal}" />
```

The above fails to render the svg icon all of a sudden (the button is still there with no icon).

Comment: How are you referencing the svg icons when using the components? Can you give us an example of a button?

Comment: @sfdcfox just added an example

Comment: Is this still an issue? When I add an icon to a community the whole component does not render. But I don't see the specific error in developer log below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you inspect your browser ,you will notice error like below

[image]

This means the SVG icons are not found for the community builder domain .What I observed is the community builder adds a /s/sfsites to the URL and this is not where the SVG icons are stored .

Hence you are out of luck unless you reach salesforce and they fix it .I did not see anywhere its documented that base components are available for community builder as well .So i would test all these before replacing any working code .

Note the same thing with below components

1.lightning:icon

2.lightning:buttonMenu

So test any base components before adopting and replacing with previous code

**Update**

Looks like R&D has resolved the issue for now and works as expected

Comment: The thing is, these were working just last week inside of a community context. While I understand that Salesforce does not explicitly say these components are available for communities I would expect the inverse: components are available for communities unless they specify that the components require one.app.

Comment: @D.S I guess you will have to raise a case with support and sort this with them on whats going on

Comment: I'll try doing that. Support has recently been on a spree of instantly closing my cases that involve any development related platform bugs because I don't have premier support. Are you aware of any other channels to report a platform bug to Salesforce?

Comment: @D.S Being an MVP I have option to open a premier support case .DM me on my MVP email that you find on my profile and i will get you a premier support case raised on your behalf .Thanks

Comment: 15003099 is the case and logged .Will update you how that goes

Comment: @Mohith Shrivastava : Quick question ... how is the static resource being referenced using ltng:require or using extends="force:slds"

Comment: @Sumuga Its not an app ,its a community component which cannot be extended .Also we do not need ltng:require as we assume slds is inbuilt into builder

Comment: Right .. my bad .. missed out on the community part ..

Comment: Thank you so much for opening that case, let me know if you need more information from me.

Comment: @D.S Still waiting to hear from the R&D team and will post once i hear from them

Comment: @D.S R&D says its fixed .Can you verify it ,else will keep the case open .Thanks

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I am on na38 and the problem is still there. It seems like whatever update they made recently also tanked my existing community. The '/s' url now returns "URL Not Found" instead of loading the community app. I spun up a new community to test this though and the icons were still missing in both the preview mode and the live mode for the community.

Comment: I have kept case open and keeping it unresolved .Thanks ! The thing is every time they update ,one has to go and publish community to avoid that url not found issue .

Comment: @D.S R&D has confirmed that the Patch fix didn't successfully resolved an Issue and the patch for the fix is scheduled to be released in a week .

Comment: @D.S The R&D has resolved the issue now .Please mark it answered if it did help